# Redirect() to root page not including base path

Tags: asp.net-core, reverse-proxy

My app is configured in startup to have a base path since the app is being reverse proxied.

```cs
app.UsePathBase("/myapp");
```

```cs
public IActionResult OnGet()
{
    return Redirect("/en/");
}
```

However, when I visit the page, I get redirected to `/en/` instead of `/myapp/en/`

How do I redirect while including the base path?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be accomplished by preceeding the path with a tilde in the `Redirect` call.

```cs
public IActionResult OnGet()
{
    return Redirect("~/en/");
}
```