# How to path-based reverse proxy app service behind application gateway?

Tags: azure, asp.net-core, azure-web-app-service, azure-application-gateway

I have an application gateway configured with my wildcard certificate that I want to use to proxy myapp.azurewebsites.net (an ASP.NET core application) behind myapp.mywebsite.net/mypath.

I have an existing site running on myapp.mywebsite.net configured in the gateway, but I want just the `/mypath` route to point to the app service. How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Step 1 - Configuring the Gateway

1. Add a new backend target for `myapp.azurewebsites.net`
2. Add a new http setting, enable hostname override with specific domain name for `myapp.azurewebsites.net`. Don't add the path override, we want the `/mypath` to be passed to the app service.
3. Edit the existing path-based rule for the site:

   1. Add new path-based rule

      1. path=`/mypath/*`
      2. name=`mypathname` // can be whatever
      3. httpsetting=the one we just made
      4. backendpool=the one we just made

This will point `myapp.mywebsite.net/mypath` to the site

### Step 2 - Configuring the Application

#### Startup.cs - Configure

See [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/proxy-load-balancer?view=aspnetcore-3.1#deal-with-path-base-and-proxies-that-change-the-request-path) for more info.

Add the following to the very start of the Configure method. We want headers to be adjusted before all other middleware happens.

```cs
app.UseForwardedHeaders(); // Enable hostname to be derived from headers added by app gateway
app.UsePathBase("/mypath"); // Tell ASP.NET that we have a base path
```

See [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/proxy-load-balancer?view=aspnetcore-3.1#troubleshoot-1) for debugging help.

### Startup.cs - ConfigureServices

[We need to tell ASP.NET to trust the gateway headers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/proxy-load-balancer?view=aspnetcore-3.1#forwarded-headers-middleware-options-1)

```cs
services.Configure<ForwardedHeadersOptions>(options =>
{
    options.ForwardedHeaders = ForwardedHeaders.XForwardedFor | ForwardedHeaders.XForwardedProto;
    options.AllowedHosts.Add("myapp.mywebsite.net");
    options.KnownProxies.Add(IPAddress.Parse("10.my.gateway.ip"));
});
```

If you are using

```cs
services.AddMicrosoftIdentityWebAppAuthentication(config);
```

for auth, we need to override the reply url so it points to `myapp.mywebsite.net/mypath/signin-oidc` instead of `myapp.azurewebsites.net/signin-oidc`.
This can be done with:

```cs
if (!env.IsDevelopment())
{
    services.Configure<OpenIdConnectOptions>(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, options =>
    {
        // options.SaveTokens = true; // this saves the token for the downstream api
        options.Events = new OpenIdConnectEvents
        {
            OnRedirectToIdentityProvider = async ctxt =>
            {
                ctxt.ProtocolMessage.RedirectUri = "https://myapp.mywebsite.net/mypath/signin-oidc";
                await Task.Yield();
            }
        };
    });
}
```

We only run this in dev so that running our stuff locally does the default behaviour of filling the replyurl with localhost.

Comment: see also: [basepath not included in redirect issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70961180/redirect-to-root-page-not-including-base-path/70961181#70961181)